# Скрывать строки с 0

Tags: php

Есть перебор массива:

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    echo '<tr><td><strong><center>'.$n++.'</center></strong></td><td><img src="'.($arr[$index]['Addon_3']).'" width="35" height="35" class="rounded-circle"></td><td>'.($arr[$index]['user']).'</td><td>'.($arr[$index]['Total']).'</td><tr>';
}
```

Который выводит таблицу вида:
**Место Менеджер    Балл**
1 Иванов Иван   1693

Бывает что у юзера 0 баллов, как можно скрывать строки с 0 баллов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
        if($arr[$index]['Total'] != 0){
        echo '<tr><td><strong><center>'.$n++.'</center></strong></td><td><img src="'.($arr[$index]['Addon_3']).'" width="35" height="35" class="rounded-circle"></td><td>'.($arr[$index]['user']).'</td><td>'.($arr[$index]['Total']).'</td><tr>';
   }
 }
```

Если у Вас `$arr[$index]['Total']` отвечает за кол-во баллов

P.S. Метку json уберите, она не относится к Вашему вопросу. (По крайней в той его форме, в которой Вы его задали.)

Answer (score 5):

Если скрывать значит "не выводить", то вот некоторые варианты:

*пропуск итерации:*

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    if(!$value['total']) continue;
```

*предварительная фильтрация:*

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($v){ return $v['total']; })
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
```

Если под не скрывать значит именно скрывать, но оставлять в html-коде, следует прописать соответствующие классы или стили `css`

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
   $hide = $value['total'] ? "" : 'style="display:none;"';
   echo '<tr'.$hide.'>  ..... <tr>';
}
```

Comment: @splash58 с какого перепугу?